# Filter datasource against another datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm in a situation where I have two different Kendo UI Datasources, and they both contain a field called "ID".

Datasource1
Datasource2

Now I need to to the following:

1. First apply filter and group to Datasource 1 (this works fine)
2. Then populate a listView only with the items which has an ID that is also part of Datasource2

I tried doing this with a script in the listView template, but when items are "excluded" it outputs an empty li-element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from Telerik support to solve this. Here is the solution they proposed:

As there is not built-in functionality that does the functionality that you are looking for, you will need to implement it manually. First you will need to filter the dataSource then loop through the results and get the items from the second dataSource with the ID that match the one you are looking for (using the get()) method. Then you can push the items in a new dataSource that you can use to show the ListView template.

It works great.